# three.js - how to replace a mesh geometry w/o recreating the mesh

Tags: three.js, webgl, mesh

I'm loading several STL files (one by one) into the same scene. Those files are different LODs of the same model (from low-poly to high-poly). I'd like to simulate a continuous model update from low to high resolution.

I tried to create a separate mesh for each LOD and add it to the scene when removing the previous one. Unfortunately, as the LODs get bigger, there is a significant delay in rendering.

See the [example](http://simonvz.github.io/WebglExs/webgl_loader_bulk_stl-cane.html) and [full code](https://github.com/SimonVZ/treejs-1/blob/master/webgl_loader_bulk_stl-cane.html)

My questions: 
- would it help if I just replace the geometry in the same mesh without recreating the mesh? If so, how to force rendering update? I tried to use `mesh.setGeometry`, but it doesn't seems to work for STL geometry - the new geometry is shown (perfectly works for Cube, for some reason). 
- is it possible to speed up the update somehow by any sort of pre-calculations or caching?

Thanks a lot in advance for any hints.
Simon

Comment: Can't you use the LOD mechanism already existing in three js ? See https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_lod.html for eg

Comment: @Popov : The LOD example has exactly same problems - each LOD level is actually a separate Mesh object and there is a visible delay when several LODs switch levels at the same time. I thought that replacing geometry instead of recreating the Mesh object will help, but can't figure out how to make it update itself on the screen. LOD object has `update()` method - I'll try something similar.

Comment: Links not working anymore!

Comment: did you tried to dispose the geometry before assigning it ?

Comment: What worked for me is `mesh.geometry = newGeometry;  mesh.updateMatrix();`